# Identify an event date time based on a prior event

Tags: plsql

I have an Oracle DB table that contains some information on users of a gaming website. Each gamer has a unique gamer_id and gets a new session_id assigned for each gaming session. A gaming session typically spans multiple weeks and the table has an entry per day for the gaming session per gamer. A gamer may or may not collect bonus points daily and this information is recorded in the bonus_points column.

I want to identify gamers who have been collecting bonus points every 7 days, starting from the session_start_dt_tm and ending with the session_end_dt_tm. So for example if the session_start_dt_tm for a gamer was JUL-02-2020 I would first like to determine if they had any day between JUL-02-2020 to JUL-08-2020 inclusive where bonus points were collected. Let's say this gamer had bonus points on JUL-06-2020, in that case their next 7 days bucket will restart from JUL-06-2020 and end on JUL-12-2020 and so on until either the session_end_dt_tm is reached or if the session is still active then session_end_dt_tm would be NULL.

Lastly I would like to sum up the number of 7 day buckets grouped per player where they had bonus points.

Sample data:

```
gamer_id,session_id,session_start_dt_tm,session_calendar_day,bonus_points,session_end_dt_tm
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-02,0,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-03,0,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-04,0,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-05,0,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-06,5,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-07,11,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-08,0,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-09,0,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-10,0,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-11,0,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-12,0,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-13,0,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-14,0,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-15,0,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-16,0,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-17,4,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-18,1,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-19,1,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-20,5,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-21,0,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-22,0,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-23,8,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-24,6,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-25,0,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-26,3,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-27,1,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-28,1,2020-07-29 20:21:18
1h22-hd3u-77-gue8,7119,2020-07-02 17:30:21,2020-07-29,2,2020-07-29 20:21:18
77df-jgf9-47-q10b,819472,2020-09-24 03:00:11,2020-09-24,3,null
77df-jgf9-47-q10b,819472,2020-09-24 03:00:11,2020-09-25,7,null
77df-jgf9-47-q10b,819472,2020-09-24 03:00:11,2020-09-26,2,null
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a good place to start would be the Oracle analytic functions.  What have you tried thus far, and do you have some specific questions related to what you have tried?